# $G$ has order $p^a$, then the center of $G$ counts more than the identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This question makes no sense to me. I don't know what it means by "counts more than the identity". Then, the exercise gives me a hint: "break G into equivalence classes of conjugacy elements and see that an element belongs to the center iff it is its own conjugate"

I understand that, by the definition, an element $x$ belongs to the center of $G$ is, for all $g\in G$, we have that $xg = gx$. This implies that $x = gxg^{-1}$. I think the exercise is asking me to break each $x$ like this. But then I don't know what it is asking for, and I know if you guys could understand it by the title, but maybe the hint tells about what's expected to be the answer. Could somebody help me?

> UPDATE:
>
> With a GREAT help of [Ben West](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/37097/ben-west) in the answers, I was able to
>   synthetize this proof by using a result [previously asked by my
>   book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400267/g-finite-the-number-of-distinct-conjugates-of-x-is-the-index-of-the-normali/1400300?noredirect=1), so I didn't need to use the orbit stabilizer theorem as he
>   did, so I'll leave this proof here:
>
> Lets take all the conjugacy classes  of $G$, that is:
>
> $$Gx = \{g\cdot x: g \in G\} = \{gxg^{-1}: g\in G\}$$
>
> Now, observe that $x\in Z(G)$  if and only if $gx=xg$, that is,
>   $gxg^{−1} =x$  for all $g∈G$ . So $x\in Z(G)$  if and only if its
>   conjugacy class is the singleton $\{x\}$.  Then, there will be two
>   cases: the conjugacy classes that have only $1$ element, here called
>   $g_k$, and the ones that have more than $1$ element, here called
>   $C_G(x)$. Since the conjugacy classes partition the group, we must have:
>
> $$|G| = \sum |g_k| + \sum |C_k|$$
>
> but $\sum |g_k|$ is exactly |$\text{Center}(G)$|, and $C_k(x)$ is the
>   $k$-$th$ conjugacy class with more than $1$ element.
>
> By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400267/g-finite-the-number-of-distinct-conjugates-of-x-is-the-index-of-the-normali/1400300?noredirect=1) question (which were presented for me before this exercise, as a
>   hint), we have that the cardinality of the conjugacy class is
>
> $|C_k|=|G|/|N_G(x)| \implies  |C_k||N_G(x)| = |G|$
>
> Therefore, we have that:
>
> $$p^a = |G| = |Z(G)| + \sum |C_k|$$
>   Since $|C_k|$ divides the order of the group, looking at the equation $\text{mod $p$}$ gives us:
>
> $$0 = |Z(G)| \ \ mod \ p \implies Z(G) \text{ contains more than the
> identity}$$

Curiosity:

> For just one element, the normalizer is the equivalence class:
>
> $N_G(x)=\{g\in G:gxg^{-1}\subseteq\{x\}\}=\{g\in G:gxg^{-1}=x\}=C_G(x)$

Comment: It looks as if you are asked to show there is an element other than the identity in the centre, that the centre has more than one element.

Comment: @AndréNicolas nice! Any hints in how this is related to the element having order multiple of a prime?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs *Power*, not multiple.

Comment: This is a standard theorem proved in almost any text on group theory (in the one standard, textbook way). If you really want an intuitive understanding of this fact, you absolutely need to have an understanding of group actions and the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we can define an equivalence relation on $G$ by $g\sim h$ if $g$ and $h$ are conjugate. This implies that the conjugacy classes partition the group $G$.

Observe that $x\in Z(G)$ if and only if $gx=xg$, that is, $gxg^{-1}=x$ for all $g\in G$. So $x\in Z(G)$ if and only if its conjugacy class is the singleton $\{x\}$.

Let $G$ act on itself by conjugation, that is, we define the action $g\cdot x=gxg^{-1}$. For $x\in G$, the orbit 
$$
Gx=\{g\cdot x:g\in G\}=\{gxg^{-1}:g\in G\}
$$ is precisely the conjugacy class containing $x$, by definition more or less.

For good measure, the stabilizer $G_x$ of $x$ is
$$
G_x=\{g\in G:g\cdot x=x\}=\{g\in G:gxg^{-1}=x\}=C_G(x),
$$
so the stabilizer of $x$ is just the centralizer in this case.

By the [Orbit=Stabilizer Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem), we have
$$
|Gx|=\frac{|G|}{|G_x|}=\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}.
$$

Now write $Z(G)=\{e,g_2,\dots,g_k\}$, it is precisely the union of all conjugacy classes which are singletons, as observed above. Let $C_1,\dots,C_m$ be the remaining conjugacy classes which are not singletons, so that $\{e\},\{g_2\},\dots,\{g_k\},C_1,\dots,C_m$ are all the conjugacy classes of $G$, hence partition $G$.

This means
$$
|G|=|\{e\}|+|\{g_2\}|+\cdots+|\{g_k\}|+\sum_{i=1}^m |C_i|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{i=1}^m|C_i|\qquad(\ast).
$$

Pick $x_i\in C_i$. So $Gx_i=C_i$, since the conjugacy class of $x_i$ is just its orbit under the conjugation action. So by Orbit-Stabilizer,
$$
|C_i|=|Gx_i|=\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x_i)|}
$$
implying $|C_i||C_G(x_i)|=|G|$, which means $|C_i|$ divides $|G|$. Note that nothing here has assumed $|G|=p^a$ yet. Now assume $|G|=p^a$, hence  each $|C_i|$ is a power of $p$ itself, not equal to $1$ since we have $|C_i|>1$ by definition.

Reducing the equation $(\ast)$ modulo $p$ yields
$$
0\equiv |Z(G)|\pmod{p}.
$$

It follows that $Z(G)\neq\{e\}$, because $0\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. So $Z(G)$ must contain more than the identity.

Comment: I should note the equation $(\ast)$ is the famous class equation, which is the way I've usually seen this result derived.

Comment: why $|Z(G)|$ is the sum of the orders of all singletons?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Those aren't just any singletons, those are the singleton conjugacy classes, which are precisely the elements of $Z(G)$ (see the second paragraph of the answer). So adding them up is the same as counting the elements of $Z(G)$.

Comment: I'm 90% at understanding this. Could you please be more clear in the part that you say $Gx_i=C_i$?

Comment: I'm just confused because my book never mentioned the orbit stabilizer theorem, he just mentions this exercise: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400267/g-finite-the-number-of-distinct-conjugates-of-x-is-the-index-of-the-normali/1400300?noredirect=1 and then asks for this one. Is there any relation between these two that can take a shortcut and not use the orbit stabilizer theorem?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs By definition, if $C$ is a conjugacy class, it consists of the class of elements which are all conjugate to each other. So if $x\in C$, $x$ is conjugate precisely to the other elements in $C$, so $C$ is the conjugacy class of $x$. Since the orbit of $x$ is also its conjugacy class (see third paragraph), $Gx$ and $C$ must be the same.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs For the second comment, the normalizer and centralizer are the same in the case of a single element: $$N_G(x)=\{g\in G:gxg^{-1}\subseteq\{x\}\}=\{g\in G:gxg^{-1}=x\}=C_G(x).$$ So that exercise seems like it's asking you to prove a special case of the orbit stabilizer theorem with the conjugation action.

Comment: I have a feeling that the previous exercise is giving me a shortcut so I don't need to use the orbit stabilizer theorem. I'm saying this because I don't think I'll be able to use this theorem in a test.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs If you have that result, it says the number of conjugates of $x$ (that is, the cardinality of its conjugacy class) is the index of $N_G(x)$, which means the cardinality of the conjugacy class $C$ of $x$ is $|C|=|G|/|N_G(x)|$. This now gives $|C||N_G(x)|=|G|$, which is what is needed to prove $|C|$ divides $|G|$. So you can jump over any uses of the Orbit-Stabilizer above, although that is the more general phenomenon.

Comment: Could you look at my update in the question, using the shortcut?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs It's more or less right, you should have cardinality signs around the $g_k$ and $C_k$, and $\sum g_k$ is $Center(G)$ should be $\sum |g_k|=|Z(G)|$, you need to add _numbers_ not group elements. Lastly, it should be $|C_k|=|G|/|N_G(x)|$ for any particular $x\in C_k$, this applies to each individual conjugacy class. It doesn't make sense to sum up conjugacy classes, they're not numbers.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look now?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Yes, that's better. There's no need to introduce $|C|$ in the last equation, just leave it as $\sum |C_k|$, this whole sum will vanish mod $p$ since you've shown in the previous line that each summand $|C_k|$ divides $|G|$.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine "counts" is a typo for "contains."

As to the problem itself: if $G$ is a group, a *conjugacy class* in $G$ is a set of the form $C_z=\{x: \exists y(x=yzy^{-1})\}$ for some $z\in G$. You know that the following are equivalent:

- $z$ is in the center of $G$;
- the conjugacy class $C_z$ of $z$ has exactly one element.

Moreover, you know that the center has at least one element, the identity - that is, there is at least one singleton conjugacy class. And the group itself is a disjoint union of conjugacy classes.

Finally, you should also know that the size of a conjugacy class divides the order of the whole group.

So the question is: can you put these things together? Suppos $G$ has order $p^a$ for some prime $p$, and $a\not=0$. Since the size of each conjugacy class divides $p^a$, we know that each conjugacy class either has size a multiple of $p$, or has exactly one element. Now, what happens if there is only one conjugacy class with exactly one element? (HINT: add the sizes of the conjugacy classes mod p . . .)

Comment: Maybe not a typo, could be unidiomatically translated from Spanish.

Comment: Noah, somehow your answer looks like the C.E. in words . . . or am I missing something?  Cheers!

Comment: I would still call that a typo, but maybe I'm defining "typo" too broadly.

Comment: @RobertLewis Sorry, what is "the C.E."?

Comment: @noah schweber:  I was going to type "class equation" but didn't want to give too much away (too soon)!

Comment: why the size of a conjugacy class divides the order of the whole group?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs  Try showing that $|\operatorname{class}(x)|= [G:C_G(x)]$: in words, that the number of elements in the same conjugacy class as $x$ is equal to the index of the centralizer of $x$ in $G$.  The hint for that is to consider when $gxg^{-1}=hxh^{-1}$ for $h,g\in G$.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Ben West did a great post below. It would be nice if you could show what happens when $gxg^{-1}=hxh^{-1}$

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs That is a routine thing to do that you should really try to work out for yourself.  Just find other equivalent ways of writing that identity and interpret them.

Answer (score 1):

Proof: $G$ acts on $\Omega := N$ by conjugation, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$,  and $C_{\Omega}(P) = Z(P) \cap N$.
Since $N$ is a $p$-group:

${|C_{\Omega}(P)| \equiv |Ω| \equiv 0} {\mod p}$

Now $1\in C_{\Omega}(P)$  gives  $| C_{\Omega}(P)| \geq p$.  In particuar, let $N=G$ means $|Z(G)|\geq p$